# Does parse.com support batch operations for push notifications?

Tags: parse-platform

I am attempting to do a batch push notification request using the parse rest API.

`curl -X POST
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: redacted"
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: redacted"
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
-d '{
"requests": [{
  "method": "POST",
  "path": "/1/push/",
  "body": {
    "channels": ["redacted"],
    "deviceType": "ios",
    "badge": 1,
    "data": {
      "alert": "Hello",
      "badge": 1,
      "key": "status"
    }
  }
}] 
https://api.parse.com/1/batch`

And am receiving the error:

`{"code":107,"error":"Method 'POST' to '/1/push/' not supported in batch operations."}`

Answer (score 0):

You are already indicating POST in CURL. The Parse push api is not `batch`. Push is sent to registered devices in Parse (associated with a certificate from Apple) and those matching your push criteria. Your push message should look more like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: " \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "channels": { 
            "$in": ["channel1","channel2","channel3"]
           },
          "deviceType": "ios"
        },
        "data": {
          "alert": "Alert message here."
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

There are various examples in the docs. The above is from the [help](https://www.parse.com/questions/sending-push-notifications-using-rest-to-multiple-channels-in-addition-to-a-where-query) forum.